# I've noticed I have a problem with NOT passing arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, arguments

I'm a self taught C++ programmer. I mainly learned off of UE4 and I still have a ways to go. I'm taking computer science in school and I'm in CSC 211 (thats the second phase I guess? if class numbers arent universal). I noticed though in class that my teachers, and other students often pass arguments a lot. By a lot, I mean A LOT. For instance, we had a lab that was to create a check after someone has input what they'd like to have inside of a restaurant. I eventually got stuck and looked it up. I saw a lot of things such as : `void CreateMenu(Menu MenuArray[])` so I eventually followed the tutorial and I got everything right. But when I program I do a lot of things like this (code from my UE4)

```
void AFPSCharacter::ServerFire_Implementation()
{
if (Item && Item->bPickedUp) {
        if (GetLocalRole() == ROLE_Authority) {
            NetFire();
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Server Fire"));
        }
    }
}
```

I know this code can look A LOT nicer and I guess my questions are:

**How do you know when to pass arguments?**

**Why would you pass arguments even if you aren't using the variable at that time**?

**What is the difference between `void CreateMenu()` and `void CreateMenu(Menu MenuArray[])` if a variable of MenuArray[] already exists and you can just update it without passing arguments?**

Comment: _"I guess i meant passing parameters"_ No, that's just a different wording for the same thing. Your question doesn't add much value here. That's all already covered by any decent beginners book, or tutorial. If you want to know when to pass aparameters, take a look at the function declaration (or the reference documentation).

Comment: Okay but not everyone is a professional programmer so idk why im getting downvotes. I just want to know how to make my programming better. The compiler doesnt tell you how to think..? Like when would you pass a parameter vs not passing one??

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about design decision "should a function take parameters or should it use class members"? Commonly, the decision is far from obvious. There's no rule to choose one or another. It kind of boils down to "should this value be available for multiple function calls?" and/or "is it within class responsibility to know about this value?"

Comment: @Yksisarvinen thank you for your answer! Okay so , just so I can make sure we're both on the same page. I mean something like this: int add(int 1, int 2) { return int1+int2} vs int add(){ //values already initialized return num1 + num2} Is the difference just between the ease of adding both / that you can plug in whatever variable you'd like?

Comment: @mathew OK, now I get your concern. In case you want to know _When to **take** parameters for a function implementation?_. I believe that's what caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thats correct, when would you take parameters vs not taking them

Comment: _@mathew_ As @Yksisarvinen mentioned, if you have a class member variable already, you'll not need a parameter for the function, unless you wan't it to work with a different value passed by the caller as well. It really depends, and is hard to answer in general.

Comment: You might want to review [ask], in particular the parts about pretending you are talking to a busy colleague and about making the first paragraph engaging and informative. I got halfway through your first paragraph before I decided it was taking to long to get from your life story to your question. So I stopped reading and posted this comment. (Others might have stopped reading and downvoted.) Hopefully you have not lost too many readers and can still get an answer. Next time, please consider asking your question first. If you must provide a biography, do that at the end.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay so it's really just a thinking problem I guess lol. Thank you!

Comment: @JaMiT thank you I guess I added too much background info. Just wanted to make the question thorough so that people knew what was going on and where I was coming from but I guess that's not needed

Comment: @mathew Well, a good commented code example sometimes tells more than all the prose.

Comment: In OOP, there are ownership issues, and a c++ user defined class is often used to package both 1) the data and 2) the operations that apply to that data  ... consider reviewing https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of to "not pass arguments":

- edit a class member variable
- edit a global variable (or at least a variable that is "global" to your function, meaning the function knows about it implicitly)

If you want to know about the first bullet point (member vs reference parameter), that will be a more stylistic answer, but I think you are talking about the second bullet point.

the second bulletpoint (parameter vs global) is still stylistic, but the question relates to style not functionality. The short answer try to avoid global variables at all cost. This includes variables that you wouldn't necessarily think to describe as global, but are known to the function implicitly (being created in the same scope as the function).

That answers your first question. Your second and third question are basically "why?". There are a few reasons that I can think of:

- it makes it much more obvious what your function does.
- you can now reuse your function for other purposes

The first point will become very obvious to you once you start working on large or even medium sized projects. You want to make it obvious what a function does. If you modify a reference parameter this automatically does this. Even better would be returning a value from a function, and setting the variable from this value:

```
Menu* CreateMenu()
```

If you have functions that just modify data that they happen to have access to you will have a very difficult time keeping track of what function does what to which variable.

the second point gets to the point of functions: reusability.

`void CreateMenu()` can modify exactly the variable that you specify inside the function.

`void CreateMenu(Menu Menus[])` can modify any menu array you happen to pass in. Imagine you need to create another menu somewhere down the line. Some of that logic (of not all) will be shared with this version of CreateMenu. Imagine you need to create 10 more menus... Imagine, you suddenly need to change the menu creation logic, after implementing 10 versions of CreateMenu...

In short, passing parameters allows your function to be reused down the line which can save you a ton of work.

To touch directly on the second question (now that the reason for passing variables is clear), a function is a machine. It does something based on the input given. If you are passing parameters that aren't necessary for the machine to give you what you want, you should consider rewriting your function. If the parameters are only necessary "sometimes" and other times they don't do anything, it is possible that your function is poorly written. It is also possible that it is worth it to live with it.

Comment: Some parts of your answer are relevant and possibly useful, but some parts are unclear.   Also, since this is question with C++ tags, it would help if your description didn't describe things in a manner that is flatly incorrect in C++.  For example, you imply that it is possible to return an array from a function via `Menu[] CreateMenu()`.   That is not valid C++, regardless of what type `Menu` is.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, you made it much more clear to me! I guess I have some studying to do and I should work on some projects that people have online to become a better programmer. But you really made it clear to me. I agree people do downvote for no reason a lot on this site. I guess because they expect people to know as much as they do? Its a forum and I think they forget that. Which I dont blame them, but they should turn it down a notch lol. Thank you for being kind and understanding.

Comment: @Peter sorry, you are correct. It's been a while since I used C++. I will amend.